# Replacing a class in an external package

Tags: python

I am using a package, say `Example`, and want to modify one of its class `Example.EgClass` to add a new method. I tried to inherit it by defining locally a new class `EgChild`:

```
from Example import EgClass

class EgChild(EgClass):
    def new_method(self):
        ...
```

However, I also want to use function `call1()` from package `Example`, and `EgClass` is used in `call1()`, like this:

```
def call1():
    ...
    exp = EgClass()
    ...
```

So, I have to modify `call1()` locally as well.

As `Example` is a rather complicated and well-maintained package, I can not be sure how many places `EgClass` is used in it. Moreover, I may also invoke other classes/functions from the packages which may use `EgClass`.

Is there a way to modify `EgClass` locally and safely without touching other parts of `Example`, while all usages of `EgClass` in `Example` are replaced?

Comment: This to me sounds like trying to fit ruby paradigms into python.

Comment: You could do this with `unittest.mock.patch`, but I wouldn't recommend it.  Instead I'd fork the package and modify it to support dependency injection (i.e. anything that uses `EgClass` should take an optional `EgClass` argument or factory function rather than instantiating `EgClass` directly).  Either that or rethink your idea of adding this method to `EgClass` -- if it's a new method entirely why is it important for this package (which won't ever call that method) to use your subclass?

Comment: You don't really need `patch`; you can monkey patch the name with `import Example; ...; Example.EgClass = EgChild`, then `call1` will use the correct class when it looks up the name `EgClass`. But such patching may only get you so far; a local fork may be the better solution.

Comment: If all you need is add a new method, can't you just use a free function instead?